# Laravel Personal Access token Expiration

Tags: laravel-passport

When do Passport Personal Access tokens exactly expire? Is it one year or they never expire?
In the doc, it says "Personal access tokens are always long-lived. Their lifetime is not modified when using the tokensExpireIn or refreshTokensExpireIn methods."
How much is long-lived? Is there any way to make them NEVER expire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is 1 year from date of creation.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to make them last forever?

Comment: you cannot set its expiration time